# Create an update page(using SQLFORM) to update a tuple of a table

Tags: python, web2py

I am passing the primary key of the table whose tuple I want to update.
This is the view from where I am passing the product_id.

```
{{for row in rows:}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{=x}}{{x=x+1}}</td>
            <td>{{=row.product_id}}</td>
            <!-- EDIT -->
            <td><form action="{{=URL('pro_edit')}}" method="post">
                <input name="pid" value="{{=row.product_id}}" type="hidden">
                <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                </form></td>
       <tr> {{pass}}
```

Now this is the controller where I am fetching it. I tried 2 things

```
testform = SQLFORM(db.products,db(db.products.product_id==request.post_vars.pid).select(), 
fields=['product_id','price','pro_type','tags','category','description']))
return dict(form=testform)

       --------------OR-------------

dform = SQLFORM(db.products,record=db(db.products.product_id==request.post_vars.pid).select(),
fields=['product_id','price','pro_type','tags','category','description'])
return dict(form=dform)
```

But this is not working.
Its generating error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db(db.products.product_id==request.post_vars.pid).select()
```

Even though the above returns only a single record, it is a `Rows` object rather than a `Row` object, so you must explicitly extract the first row, which you can do as follows:

```
db(db.products.product_id==request.post_vars.pid).select().first()
```

Another option is to use the following shortcut:

```
db.products(product_id=request.post_vars.pid)
```

Comment: 1) The shortcut you specified isn't working. It says that 'product_id' is not a global name. It works fine if I gives full reference'db.products.product_id'.
2) Even after using first(), its not working. Showing error-
'Row' object has no attribute 'select'.

Comment: I got it. Actually I was passing the **row** object in the **record** field. Instead I had to pass the query only. So on removing the select(), it worked.

Comment: hey I am getting the form in the view, but when I am submitting it, a new blank form is generated(which is undesired). Also the updates I made in the form are not replicated to db but instead the new form entry is getting inserted to db.
I just inserted this before return locals()
**if dform.process().accepted:
        session.flash = 'Successfully Updated'
        redirect(URL('pro_list'))**

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the shortcut provided above. `db.products(product_id=request.post_vars.pid)` is a shortcut for the complete `db(db.products.product_id==request.post_vars.pid).select().first()`. It sounds like you attempted to append `.select().first()` to the shortcut, which is not correct. The shortcut produces a `Row` object, not a query, so you are indeed passing a `Row` object as the "record" argument to `SQLFORM` (a query object would not work).

Comment: If the record is not getting updated upon submission, I suspect you have a problem elsewhere in you code. You might consider posting more complete code on the web2py Google Group for additional help.